# Cannot allocate memory QEMU

Tags: memory, virtual-machine, qemu

I'm currently running Windows 10. I tried to use QEMU on my PC to emulate Windows 98 Live CD, everything worked perfectly until I tried to allocate more memory than the default(128MB).

I tried to use this:

```
    Start QEMU.EXE -m 512M -cdrom (What ever goes here)
```

but the QEMU windows appears, and disappears in one second, I can't even see anything that may have displayed.

Any helps?(Please do not suggest me to use other emulators. Because this is the only one that is portable and do not require administrator permission to run I know so far. Or, please suggest another virtual machine that is portable and administrator-permission-less to run. Thanks!)

Comment: The switch to specify RAM size is `-m` not `-r`.

Comment: Sorry, I typed wrong. I was using -m but not working :(

Comment: Check out this tool to take screen shots at milliseconds with appened date stamp names to capture the full error to potentially assist in getting more detail of the error that needs rectified. Should be rather simple such as download, put is a directory and then kick it off (via CMD) just before you run and then end it after the error disappears, look through screen shots for the one with full detail needed  and update your question with it . . . http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html   Example: `nircmd.exe loop 10 60 savescreenshot c:\temp\scr~$currdate.MM_dd_yyyy$-~$currtime.HH_mm_ss$.png`

Comment: This one may work well too. . . http://www.ducklink.com/p/command-line-screen-capture/